# Prettier: Preserve parenthesis around multiline expressions?

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

Prettier is removing the parenthesis wrapping multiline expressions in our code.  Is there any way to convince prettier to ignore these?

Input (with parenthesis I want to preserve):

```
  const result = (foo, bar) => (
    someObject.someFunction(foo).anotherFunction(bar)
  );
```

Prettier output:

```
  const result = (foo, bar) =>
    someObject.someFunction(foo).anotherFunction(bar);
```

I see that prettier will [preserve parenthesis around multiline JSX](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2180).  And there was a discussion of [allowing parenthesis around general expressions](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2065), which to me seemed to be closed without resolution.

We have a large codebase adhering to the Airbnb Style Guide (which uses the default ESLint rule [`implicit-arrow-linebreak: 'beside'`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/implicit-arrow-linebreak)).  This convention appears hundreds if not thousands of times in our code.